# segue from UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to `segue` data from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController`.
The data in `UIViewController` is coming from `PFTableViewController` and I want to pass that data to another `TableViewController`.

For passing to ViewController `didSelect` method is used but I have no idea how can I segue from `viewController` to `TableViewController`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let destinationToFVC:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FVCont") as! ViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let row1 = Int(indexPath.row)
        destinationToFVC.currentObject = objects?[row1] as! PFObject!


    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationToFVC, animated: true)

}
```

I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can launch the segue manually from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, with the the method `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

You need to create a custom segue in your Storyboard from your `UIViewController` to your `UITableViewController` and set an `Identifier` for it, you can press `Ctrl` + `Click` from your `UIViewController` to the next to create the custom segue and then select the segue and in the **Attributes Inspector** set the Identifier for the segue just a this picture:

[image]

Then you can in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` launch the segue manually as in this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     // the identifier of the segue is the same you set in the Attributes Inspector
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: self)
}
```

And of course you need to implement the method `prepareForSegue` to pass the data from your `UIViewController` to your `UITableView` like in this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "mySegueID") {
        // in this line you need to set the name of the class of your `UITableViewController` 
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as UITableViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        destinationToFVC.currentObject = objects?[indexPath] as! PFObject!
    }
}
```

> **EDIT:**

If you want to perform your segue from an `UIButton` to the `UITableViewController` it's the same logic, just create the custom segue in your Storyboard and then call the `prepareForSegue` like in the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if (segue.identifier == "mySegueID") {
       // in this line you need to set the name of the class of your `UITableViewController` 
       let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as UITableViewController
       / here you need to pass the data using the reference viewController
   }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks @Victor but there's a problem I can't use the above syntax as I'm trying segue from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController` and the above syntax can be used in `UITableViewController` Protocol according to how much till now I have learnt `Swift and Xcode`

Comment: @SabhaySardana How do you want to make a segue, from a `UIButton`, manually or something else?

Comment: with button in the ViewController.