# How can I segue to another view controller by clicking a view?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I specifically want to do this using the storyboard. Is that possible? If not what are the options using swift?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can make a segue from a `UIView` directly (Control-drag), according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html):

> On the storyboard, Control-drag from an object (such as a button, a table view cell, or a tab view item) in one scene to another scene.

But you can handle the tap inside your `UIView` with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and then follow one of the two following options:

- Define an `@IBAction` for the `UITapGestureRecognizer`  and inside it  you can perform a manual segue very easily to other scene.

  You can see my answer here to see step-by-step how to launch a manual segue [segue from UIViewController to UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828330/segue-from-uiviewcontroller-to-uitableviewcontroller/34829100#34829100)
- Or You can directly from the `UITapGestureRecognizer` launch the segue to the another scene once it's set to the `UIView`

[image]

It's up to you.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclusively use story board I don't think you can initiate a segue from touching a view. However, you can use a button then hold ctr and click the button and drag the line that appears to the new view controller. You can delete the text of the button and give it a background color or even add and image to it so that it will look like a view.

Comment: Problem is, I want to have two labels inside... and within the button that doesn't seem to be possible. I'm thinking I have to make my own custom view with links to the labels that then detects the touchUpInside and programmatically segues into other ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can control drag from one vc to another vc, then configure the segue's identifier in attribute inspector on the right panel of Xcode.

In your code, for example the button's handler,

You can call:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueID" sender:self];`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (touch.view == YOURVIEW)
    {
       //Perform Navigation
    }
}
```